# expressing $p , p(p+1) , p(p+1)(p+2)$ as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm working on arithmetical analysis and more specifically on finite differences. I want to create a series consisting of the following terms : 
$$f(x_{0} + ph) = f_{0}+ p\Delta f_{0}+ \frac{p(p+1)}{2!} \Delta^{2}f_{0} + \frac{p(p+1)(p+2)}{3!} \Delta^{3}f_{0} + ....$$

but I can't think a way of expressing $$ p , p(p+1) , p(p+1)(p+2) $$ 
in a form that can be used in a series. 
Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: See [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
p(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(p+n)=\dfrac{(p+n)!}{(p-1)!}=p\dfrac{(p+n)!}{p!}
$$

can works?

Comment: Well I've come across a problem. We can use factorial only if p and ( p+ n ) are non-negative integers. What are my options if p is a real number ?

Comment: @ΑθηνάΠαπαδοπούλου: See [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).